# Fix permissions for rpm/setuptools packaging

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, rpm

I have a project that requires post-install hooks for deployment.  My method is to use setuptools to generate the skeleton rpm spec file and tar the source files.

The problem is that I don't know how to control permissions with this method.  The spec file looks like:

```
%install
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT --record=INSTALLED_FILES

%files -f INSTALLED_FILES
%defattr(755,%{user},%{user})
```

This works out reasonably well: in that all files get set set to the appropriate user and permissions.  But the directories don't have the attributes set on them.  I can't tell whether this is a problem, but it does seem strange: all the directories are owned by root with 755 permissions.  Does anyone know a good (reasonably standard) way to make the directories owned by `user`?  I ask because my company tends to prefer packaging applications that will deploy under an application-specific role-account.  When I use setuptools to put the results in site-packages, `.pyc` files are copied over.  But if I want to create a config file directory off the path, it seems like a good amount to work around.

Comment: Side notice: %files -f INSTALLED_FILES is usually considered to be a bad practice. You will get unreliable and unpredictable rpm directories ownership this way. Really, it is not hard to manually list installed dirs/files for a python package (since you do not need to list each file individually), but this simplifies maintenance and upgrades, and provides more predictable results.

Answer (score 3):

> %defattr(755,%{user},%{user})

That line sets the default permissions, user, and group ownership on all files.  You can override the default with something like:

```
%attr(644, <username>, <username>) </path/to/file>
```

If you want the default to be owned by a user other than root, then you probably need to define the 'user' macro up at the top of the spec:

```
%define user myusername
```